# I wish to create a translator using Python 3

Tags: python, morse-code

I am looking to create a translator with Python that converts English into Morse Code.  I was able to get it working but would like to improve it.

Here is what I have:

```
morse = {'A': '.-',     'B': '-...',   'C': '-.-.', 
    'D': '-..',    'E': '.',      'F': '..-.',
    'G': '--.',    'H': '....',   'I': '..',
    'J': '.---',   'K': '-.-',    'L': '.-..',
    'M': '--',     'N': '-.',     'O': '---',
    'P': '.--.',   'Q': '--.-',   'R': '.-.',
    'S': '...',    'T': '-',      'U': '..-',
    'V': '...-',   'W': '.--',    'X': '-..-',
    'Y': '-.--',   'Z': '--..',

    '0': '-----',  '1': '.----',  '2': '..---',
    '3': '...--',  '4': '....-',  '5': '.....',
    '6': '-....',  '7': '--...',  '8': '---..',
    '9': '----.'}
```

print (morse['G'])

Now this works fine, but I would like for it to prompt me with a question such as "What would you like to translate?" and then have someone type (as a example) "This will will be converted to Morse Code".  and have whatever is typed converted.  Does anyone know a way to do this? it seems like such a hassle to type  "print (morse['G'])" for each letter.

Comment: Have you tried asking for help from your professor, TA, teacher, department tutors, &c.? Helping you get started with this sort of thing is their job, and they'll be able to give you better guidance with this sort of question than strangers on the Internet. StackOverflow is designed for questions about more specific sorts of problems.

Comment: Hi thank you for such a quick answer, but currently I am unable to contact him.  Would you be willing to look at my revised question and see if you could shed any light on it?  Any and all help is very much appreciative.

Comment: @McHaddish Break your problem up into steps. You need to ask a user for a string (1) and then apply your dictionary to each character of that string (2). You can Google the solutions to both (1) and (2), but I'll save you some time for (1) and point you to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: [`' '.join(`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join) [`morse.get(let,"??")`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.get#dict.get) [`for let in word)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)  this assumes that you enter all letters that are present in your `morse` dictionary, anything that is not present will be replaced with a `??`

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt users for input using the raw_input (python 2) or input (python 3) functions.
The input to these functions is the prompt that is displayed, and the function returns what is entered.

```
>stored_input = input('Please enter a line: ')
Please enter a line: Some input
>print stored_input
Some input
```

This function will return to you a string. I'll leave it up to you to learn how to break the string into its characters. Also, what if an input is not a capital letter or a number (e.g. a lower case number, or a '\')? Be sure to utilize google to figure out the rest, this question has been asked many, many times.

Comment: if you have links to where it was asked before then post links!!